# Convert timestamp(Datetime.ticks) from database to Datetime value before displaying it in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, sql-server-ce

I am using SQL server compact edition as the backend in my winform application.

I have a column **timestamp** in one of my tables. I have stored timestamp as follows :

```
DateTime dt = System.DateTime.Now;
long timestamp = dt.Ticks;
```

It stores a long value representing current date and time into the database.

I want to display table's data in a **DataGridView** control by setting its **DataSource** property.

When I retrieve table data using SQL query "select * from my-table" and attach to DataSource, it just displays timestamp as a long value.

My **question** is :
How can I convert timestamp back to DateTime value in dd-mm-yyyy format before displaying it in the DataGridView?

Comment: Can you give an example, how you bind data to datagridview? What do you use as datasource? Just datatable?

Comment: I executed SqlCeCommand and attached SqlCeResultSet to the DataSource property of the DataGridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using datatable, you can do this:

```
resultDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DateTime", typeof(DateTime)));
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    r["DateTime"] = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(r["Timestamp"]);
}
dt.Columns.Remove("Timestamp");
```

Check this to convert sqlceresultset.resultview to datatable: [Convert SQLCEResultSet resultview to datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582530/convert-sqlceresultset-resultview-to-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Datetime dt = new DateTime(longvaluefromdatabase);
```

> Initializes a new instance of the DateTime structure to a **specified number of ticks**.

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx)

Comment: I agree, this will convert long value to datetime value. But how will I reflect this change in DatagridView?