# c# - How to convert Timestamp to Date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I'm getting timestamp from xml document.Now, I want to convert Timestamp to Date format(13-May-13)

```
XmlNodeList cNodes = xncomment.SelectNodes("comment");
foreach (XmlNode node in cNodes)
{
    //I'm getting this "1372061224000" in comment-date
    string comment_date = node["creation-timestamp"].InnerText;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that a sql server timestamp value? If so, you should not be using as a datetime...

Comment: Is this what you were looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11914243/1341477

Comment: Possible Dupilcate of [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914243/convert-timestampdatetime-ticks-from-database-to-datetime-value-before-display)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Given that this looks like a Java timestamp, simply use below:

```
var dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(Math.Round(1372061224000 / 1000d)).ToLocalTime();
Console.WriteLine(dt); // Prints: 6/24/2013 10:07:04 AM
```

Comment: This isn't normal timestamp. please take care

Answer (score 9):

Finally i found how to convert **time stamp** to **Date** & **Date** to **time stamp** . I found some places in project people keep date as time stamp for get difference quickly. so in this case they use to keep the table column as Int or time stamp. now the problem is that in the application while showing the data, you need to convert it into date variable. So for that we can use the following code to convert **time stamp** to **Date**

```
int ts = 1451174400;
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(ts).ToLocalTime();
string formattedDate = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Now you can get any date format from this variable.

In the second case if you want to convert **Date** to **time stamp** then check the following code.

```
int ts = (dt.Ticks - 621356166000000000) / 10000000;
```

Where dt is the date time variable & holding a date value.

Comment: this answer is prefect for normal time stamp

Comment: This is the first working answer in so many I have browsed.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe replace this :

```
    foreach (XmlNode node in cNodes)
{
    //I'm getting this "1372061224000" in comment-date
    string comment_date = node["creation-timestamp"].InnerText;
}
```

by :

```
foreach (XmlNode node in cNodes)
{
    Datetime comment_date = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(node["creation-timestamp"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all.

Finally I got the output

```
foreach (XmlNode node in cNodes)
{
    comment_timestamp = node["creation-timestamp"].InnerText;
    DateTime comment_date1 = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt64(comment_timestamp));
    comment_date = Convert.ToDateTime(comment_date1).ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
}
```

Output:

```
01-MAY-13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **FromUnixTimeSeconds** method of **DateTimeOffset**

```
 var dateTime1 = new DateTime(2020, 4, 5, 12, 15, 12);//05.04.2020 12:15:12

 var timeStamp = new DateTimeOffset(dateTime1).ToUnixTimeSeconds(); //1586074512
```

If FromUnixTimeSeconds's result is not corresponding your original datetime, you can use LocalDateTime property of DateTimeOffset object.

```
 var dateTime2 = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(timeStamp).DateTime;//05.04.2020 08:15:12
 var dateTime3 = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(timeStamp).LocalDateTime;//05.04.2020 12:15:12
```

For more information please visit this link [DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(Int64) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimeseconds?view=netframework-4.8)